# Python error multiprocessing argparse win32

Tags: python, multiprocessing, argparse

Again (maybe) a stupid question. I write a miner for my own cryptocurrency system. On unix all is fine with my code. I use the following libs they may interferre:

- multiprocessing
- argparse

Now if i start the miner with the argparse arguments it throws me the error:

```
unrecognized arguments: --multiprocessing-fork....
```

It's true. These arguments are not catched within argparse. If i use parse_known_args it works but it spawns multiple threads of the entire program which does not work because the arguments are not delivered to the other one. Maybe this can also create an infinite loop.

Here is my example argparse code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Command line options")
parser.add_argument("--wallet", help="Defines the walletaddress to send mining rewards to", metavar="<ADDR>")
parser.add_argument("--threads", help="Defines the amount of threads <THREADS> to use (default: 1)", default="1", metavar="<THREADS>")
parser.add_argument("--node", help="Sets the target node to <NODE> (default: 'localhost')", default="localhost", metavar="<NODE>")
parser.add_argument("--node-port", help="Sets the target node port to <PORT> default: '25000')", default="25000", metavar="<PORT>")
argum, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
```

I do not have any solutions for this problem. Maybe someone can help me ?

Greetings

Comment: I am still trying to decipher what your goal is here? can you elaborate a bit more ?

Comment: Okay i have one program that starts with 4 arguments and is able to handle multiple threads/processes in itself. You can look at the sourcecode: https://github.com/bimbam2103/xsecminer